# Why I cannot show my image(.svg) that uploaded to S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've uploaded few svg image to a S3 bucket(I'v set to public-all).After I uploaded all svg images.I get each image's URL.When I clicked on those Url it just download the images for me.
Also. Does anyone know why when I use those Url in a img tag (e.g.`<img src='https://***.s3.***.amazonaws.com/***.svg` />`).It just shows a broken image

Here is my lambda function

```
'use strict'


const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new aws.S3()
const { parse } = require('aws-multipart-parser')

const response = (statusCode, data) => ({
  statusCode,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})


exports.handler = async event => {
  const inputData = parse(event, true)

  if (inputData.file) {
    try {
      const params = {
        Bucket: ***,
        region: ***,
        Key: `${inputData.file.filename}`,
        Body: inputData.file.content,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }

      const s3Response = await s3.upload(params).promise()
      return response(200, { statusCode: 200, url: s3Response['Location'] })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
      return response(500, {
        error: error.message
      })
    }
  } else {
    return response(400, {
      error: 'Please provide input file.'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't be broken if the URL is correct. Is there any error that shows up in console? @CH L

Comment: must be a cross site access issue, check browser logs

Comment: Mostly looks like incorrect mime type. Could you check the content type ) for your svg file on S3. It should be set to image/svg+xml .

Comment: I am not in front of my computer but when I click the url it just download the image for me

Comment: Ref broken image, It's because svg isn't constructed properly.  Try using a different SVG.
Ref  downloading instead of viewing, setting content type should fix that

Comment: are you not able to render svg images from s3 ONLY? or are you not able to show ANY svg image (even if it is on your local). If your case is latter, please paste your webpack config.

Comment: I am not able to render svg using the url in S3 only.Even I tried to use png. It also not working

Comment: @HarshBafna Sorry. May I ask that how to check and change the content type in S3 panel? Since this is the first time I try to use S3 as a store for an admin that can upload image using cms

Comment: @CHL select the object on S3 console. Click on actions -> Change Metadata.

Comment: @HarshBafna But what about if a user upload an image that already set the content type? It is impossible to change all object when a user upload new image

Comment: also it should be x-amz-meta   image/svg+xml?

Comment: @CHL There is an option to set the header properties while uploading any object on S3. The key will be Content-Type. If content type is not provided, S3 sets it to default.

Comment: After I change the content type. It is still a broken image ...no error in the console and Network shows that it is 200

Comment: Is it still getting downloaded?

Comment: @CHL Can you check the mime-type being received by the browser? May be you will need to do empty cache hard reload.

Comment: @HarshBafna I select an object, add a metadata`x-amz-meta image/svg+xml` and save.But when I refresh .The metadata disappeared.

Comment: Sorry....How to check the mime-type in the browser

Comment: @CHL you don't need to set x-amz-meta. You need to change the already set content-type to image/svg+xml. The value will already be available in the dropdown.

Comment: @HarshBafna oh . I can see the uploaded image in my localhost. But how to set the header when user upload any new image to S3?

Comment: @CHL are you uploading through console or using some sdk? On console you get the option to set the header in properties tab. Through SDK/aws-cli you will need to set it through code. However, first you should ensure that changing the content type resolves your problem.

Comment: @HarshBafna I use lambda and API Gateway to get the endpoint for user to upload image.The params is :``` const params = {
        Bucket: '***',
        region: '***',
        Key: `${inputData.file.filename}`,
        Body: inputData.file.content,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }
```

Comment: @CHL you can pass the Content-Type while uploading the image using the putObject API. Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax

Comment: @HarshBafna I have read that document...But I dont understand what is those syntax and where should I add these syntax...Since the lambda I write is a very simple one with only an index.js and I am not sure where should I add the header

Comment: @CHL it will be easier if you could add a sample code to your question.

Comment: I have add my lambda function to my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the content type for you svg image on S3 to "image/svg+xml".

To change the content-type through S3 console :

- Select the object on the S3 console
- Click on actions
- Click on change metadata

[image]

- Change the content-type to image/svg+xml. The value is already available in the drop down.

[image]

As you are using the API gateway to upload the images, you can set the respective content type in you putObject request.

Reference : [AWS S3 Put Object API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax)

You can refer the following AWS documentation to upload image with ContentType through JS :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: I have add my lambda to the question. Should I add the Content type via APIGATEWAY or lambda?...

Comment: @CHL : In the lambda, you can pass the ContentType parameter. However you may need to pass a different ContentType every time based on the file type being uploaded. Like image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/png etc. May be you can create a key-value pair type struct and pass the content type based on the type of file being uploaded.

Comment: Since this lambda is just for user to upload image(.svg .png etc) only. So I just need to change the params from ```const params = {
        Bucket: ***,
        region: ***,
        Key: `${inputData.file.filename}`,
        Body: inputData.file.content,
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }```   to  ```const params = {
        Bucket: ***,
        region: ***,
        Key: `${inputData.file.filename}`,
        Body: inputData.file.content,
        ACL: 'public-read', ContentType : image/svg+xml
      }``` ?

Comment: Sometimes I found that the document in AWS  is hard for me to understand

Comment: Agreed. Also lack of examples in a lot of cases.

Comment: I have started programming for 3 months only using react.And I found that something I cannot understand the document is because I have no knowledge about that but sometimes I just dont understand what it is about

Comment: You will get used to it in time. You can also look into boto3 - python SDK documentation. I find it more detailed and better documented. Also, please accept the answer in case it resolved your problem.

Comment: Great , I can upload a svg and show it in my website. thank you for helping me a lot

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue with SVGs being served from S3. On opening the `svg` url on the browser, it was working fine, but on passing the `url` in the `img`s `src` attribute gave a broken image.

After comparing my `svg` with other working `svg`s I found that below  attributes were missing in my `svg`.

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
```

On adding them it started working fine.

Something like this it has to be -

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
...
...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Front-End developers were complaining about this same issue. Blame AWS!

For some reason, they mark SVG images as `binary/octet-stream` instead of marking them as `image/svg+xml`.

My Back-End is developed in Golang and I use the official AWS SDK to Upload the files (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go). What I did to fix the problem was pass by parameter the MimeType (ContentType) of the file.

If you don't pass AWS any MimeTypes then they will try to automatically identify a MimeType for your file, however they can make a mistake in some cases. If you pass a MimeType to AWS they will use your MimeType instead of trying to identify it, and that will likely solve the problem.

In my case in Golang I used this package to be able to automatically identify the MimeType https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype

```golang
    var mimeTypePtr *string
    mime := mimetype.Detect(file)
    if mime != nil {
        mimeType := mime.String()
        mimeTypePtr = &mimeType
    }
    
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(cfg)
    result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:      os.Getenv("AWS_BUCKET"),
        Key:         filename,
        Body:        file,
        ContentType: mimeTypePtr,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case SVG image still gets forces download if its mime-type is `image/svg`
You can fix it by set the mime-type for the file is `image/svg+xml`